# how to pass the selected list value to the chart

Tags: angularjs

can anyone tell me how to pass the value what we select from list box.

list box code

```
<select size="10" id="myselection" ng-multiple="false" ng-model="selectedColors" ng-options="c.name for c in colors" style="width: 150px"></select>
<div>
    Selected Colors: {{selectedColors.name}}
    <br>
    Selected Colors: <span ng-repeat="for color in selectedColors">{{color.name}}
</div>
```

passing value code

`<div> ac-chart="chartType" ac-data="black" ac-config="config" id='chart' class='chart'></div>`

in this instead of black we need to pass the selected value of listbox .

Comment: did you try
`<div> <ac-chart="chartType" ac-data="{{selectedColors.name}}" ac-config="config" id='chart' class='chart'></div>`

Comment: yes but it not working

Comment: When using multiple and/or ng-multiple with a select, the bound model variable is always an array, even if ng-multiple="false" as you have used. So the binding expression you want is `ac-data="{{selectedColors[0].name}}"`.